# Call the value fetched by browse button in a script without executing it twice from another script in python

Tags: python, tkinter

**interface.py**

```
from tkFileDialog import askopenfilename
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
def browsefunc():
    filename = askopenfilename()
    return filename
browsebutton1 = Button(root, text="Browse",command=browsefunc, width=20)
browsebutton1.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

**main_progarm.py**

```
import interface
import csv
x=interface.browsefunc()//calling from interface
reader=csv.reader(open(aa),delimiter=',')
my_data=list(reader)
print my_data
```

I just need the csv file from interface.py browsed by browsefunc in mainprogram.py without opening the browse window twice

Comment: What's happening in your program is this: (1) interface is imported. (2) Interface calls root.mainloop() which will not return until the application is destroyed or the event loop is interrupted. The result is that when you start the application, you'll see your widgets you created in the interface module. But until you destroy the main window, the browsefunc() call in main_program is not executing. Make sense? The solution is to wait until the entire GUI is created before calling root.mainloop(). This means you call it at the end of main_program.py ... interface.root.mainloop()

Comment: The indentation of some of your code is incorrect.